# Joining a List in a different way

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

Language: C# 4.0

There is a `List<string>` with values Value1, Value2, Value3 and so on.
I would like to perform a join on the generic List so that the output should be

```
string values = "Value1, Value2 and Value3";
```

and if there is only one value

```
string values = "Value1";
```

I am currently replacing `LastIndexOf` `,` with `and`. But did not like that much.
Whats the most efficient method to join like this?

Comment: Why don't you join all elements except for the last one, then concat it manually? Your problem is quite specific, I'd just use a specific solution and get on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `String.Join(string glue, string[] array);` function for this.

```
string values = String.Join(", ", myList.ToArray());
```

Hope that helps. (*Note:* `myList` is the List you already have in your application somewhere.)

*Update:* Noticed your *and* requirement a little too late, my appologies, here is a little update:

```
string values = String.Join(", ", myList.Take(myList.Count - 1)) 
                   + " and " + myList.Last();
```

Alternatively (or maybe even better) you can use a `StringBuilder` for this, instead of string concatenation. (*Remember:* You will still have to check if you have only one value in the list.)

Update: Here is a simple extension method.

```
public static string SmartJoin(this List<string> items, string lastSeparator)
{
    string values = "";
    if(!items.Any())
    {
        return "";
    }
    if (items.Count > 1)
    {
        values = String.Format("{0} {1} {2}",
                    String.Join(", ", items.Take(items.Count - 1)),
                    lastSeparator,
                    items.Last());
    }
    else
    {
        values = items.First();
    }
    return values;
}
```

And one can call it like

```
string values = myList.SmartJoin("and");
```

Comment: actually i am joining like this. `string values = String.Join(", ", myList);` `ToArray()` is not needed in C# 4.0

Comment: all pretty good answers. i am accepting this one. @Kilzone: I am updating your answer for future use if you don't mind.

Comment: No problem, it only makes the answer better I think.

Comment: the else part is wrong: `items.ToString()` should be `items[0]`

Comment: It's still wrong. When the passed list is empty, an exception will be raised since the else-branch reads the non-existing first element.

Comment: @Jason, @Christian: updated. was away :) if one of you have downvooted please revert. @KilZone gets negatives for my bad :)

Answer (score 4):

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
{
  if (i == sb.Count - 1)
  {
    sb.Append(" and ");
  }
  else if (i > 0)
  {
    sb.Append(", ");
  }
  sb.Append(list[i])
}
```

Comment: You could save a level of indentation and it would be neater if you moved `if (i > 0)` to the `else` statement

Answer (score 3):

I personally like to use the methods from the `Enumerable`-namespace for tasks like this :)

```
List<string> values = new List<string>() { "Value1", "Value2", "Value3"};
string result = "";
if (values.Count == 1) {
    result = values[0];
}
else if (values.Count > 1 ) {
    var init = values.Take(values.Count - 1);
    var temp = init.Aggregate((acc, x) => acc + ", " + x);
    temp += " and " + values[values.Count -1];
    result = temp;
}
```

Comment: the most "efficient" not the most LINQ fancyness ;)

Comment: Being able to leave out if-else chains for special cases can result in more efficient code in the end :) But of course, a profiler can help when in doubt.

Comment: @Jason: yes :) @Christian: +1 one for this. i liked it :)

Answer (score 2):

The no-nonsense answer:

```
var sb = new StringBuilder();
for(int i = 0; i < items.Count; i++)
{
    if(i != 0)
    {
        if(i == items.Count-1) sb.Append(" and ");
        else sb.Append(", ");
    }
    sb.Append(items[i]);
}
return sb.ToString();
```

If you want to perform an operation that has a couple of special cases (no leading or trailing commas, and the last comma is actually `" and "`), the simplest way is to just write special cases.

Answer (score 1):

You can join using function like this:

```
 public string SmartJoin(string lastSeparator, List<string> array)
 {
   var lastElementPosition = array.Count - 1;
   var lastValue = array[lastElementPosition];
   array.RemoveAt(lastElementPosition);

   return String.Join(lastSeparator, new[] { String.Join(", ", array), lastValue });
 }
```

Example:

```
   var items = new List<string> { "Value1", "Value2", "Value3" };
   var result =  SmartJoin(" and ", items);
```

Comment: +1 good one. i liked the `lastSeparator` param. very thoughtful :)

Answer (score 1):

The method:

```
private static string ConvertToString(List<string> list)
{
    if (!list.Any())
    {
        return string.Empty;
    }

    if (list.Count == 1)
    {
        return list.First();
    }

    return string.Join(", ", list.Take(list.Count - 1)) + " and " + list.Last();
}
```

examples

```
var list1 = new List<string> { "Value1", "Value2", "Value3", "Value4" };
var list2 = new List<string> { "Value1", "Value2", "Value3" };
var list3 = new List<string> { "Value1", "Value2" };
var list4 = new List<string> { "Value1" };
Console.WriteLine(ConvertToString(list1));
Console.WriteLine(ConvertToString(list2));
Console.WriteLine(ConvertToString(list3));
Console.WriteLine(ConvertToString(list4));
```

NOTE: I'm using .net 4 code

UPDATE: removed unnecessary code
UPDATE2: did some code optimization used some tips form @KilZone

Answer (score 1):

```
var sb = new StringBuilder();
if (yourList.Count > 0)
{
    sb.Append(yourList[0]);

    if (yourList.Count > 1)
    {
        for (int i = 1; i < yourList.Count - 1; i++)
        {
            sb.Append(", ").Append(yourList[i]);
        }

        sb.Append(" and ").Append(yourList[yourList.Count - 1]);
    }
}
string values = sb.ToString();
```